# How do I troubleshoot Aptana debugger timeout?

Tags: php, aptana, zend-debugger

I've installed Zend Debugger on my remote Linux server. I've verified the installation by looking at `phpinfo()`.

I'm trying to debug a PHP page in Aptana 3.3.1, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
A timeout occurred when the debug server attempted to connect to the following client hosts/IPs:
-192.168.1.64
-127.0.0.1
!DefaultDebugServerConnectionTest_theClientHostIPs!

Click here for more information on setting up remote debugging.
```

Clicking "here" doesn't do anything.

I've verified that Aptana is reaching the dummy.php file, because if I delete it, I get an error message saying that dummy.php is missing. The problem seems to be that dummy.php can't connect back to me.

I've tried forwarding ports 10000 and 10137 on my router to my laptop, but it hasn't helped. Windows Firewall isn't logging any dropped packets, and Apache `error_log` doesn't show anything unusual.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks,
Shane.